# Blank space on right of website

Tags: html, css

I am creating a website and have encountered a problem where I get a load of blank space on the right in all browsers. I usually fix this by adding overflow:hidden to the wrapper div but for some reason it's not working this time. I have also experimented by adding this to the html and body tags in css but they tend to hide everything, and overflow-x does not work.

I would massively appreciate any help! You can view the website here: http://dakar.bournemouth.ac.uk/~hmonaghan

You will be able to see the code by obviously viewing the code source but if anybody needs me to post anything here I will.

Comment: looks fine in Chrome on Linux

Comment: looks fine in Chrome on OSX, too

Comment: Fine on FF, Chrome, Safari, IE7-10 under Windows.

Comment: Looks fine in Chrome on Windows as well. Using 1440p resolution.

Comment: Guys, you have to remove all the `overflow:hidden` properties on the HTML/BODY/WRAPPER in Inspect Mode to see the problem

Comment: @Paulie_D If I have to remove the `overflow:hidden`, then safe to say its not a problem. Not the question he posted at least.

Comment: @Giovanni Silveira He's asking, at least as far as I can tell, how to fix it without using overflow...which he clearly is at the moment.

Comment: @Paulie_D: "I usually fix this by adding overflow:hidden to the wrapper div but for some reason it's not working this time." - so he said its not working this time, which is clearly not the case.

Comment: @Pixelen: there are multiple issues with your design. And with that, there are multiple ways to fix it.

Comment: That's odd, I've tested on macbook pro, wide monitor, phone and tablet and have encountered the space on all of them. (you have to scroll to the right?) But I guess if you guys can't see it then there's no problem. And yes I do want to use overflow:hidden but I thought it wasn't working, which is clearly not the case.

Comment: The issue you are proposing seems to be something with how scrolling works, which not always gets solved by `overflow:hidden`, and is not really the one you mentioned. You could solve that, you dont even need the `overflow` setting to fix your issues, but again, that's not what you asked in your question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking off all the overflows and looking at it with Developer Tools it's the `nav` that's causing most of the problems.

It positioned absolutely with a width of 100% AND a margin of 26% so it's breaking out of the page.

Try reducing the nav width to c.70%...that will take care of most of the problem although there may be other issues for what's left which I suspect is related to the slider.

Comment: That was it! Thanks, it's been a little since I've done web stuff. Need to remember the basics.

Answer (score 0):

It looks OK to me in Chrome on Windows - you must have a very wide monitor. That being said, try out something similar to this CSS and let me know if it works for you:

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```